# Python C API: initialize instance member objects to NULL or None?

Tags: python, design-patterns, python-c-api

When creating a new instance of a custom class in the C API, is it preferable to initialize the member variables to `NULL` or `None`?

Comment: Could you show code? What is a member? Do you mean attribute in a dictonairy? I owuld say that `None` is the case if they can be accessed by Python.